# Heading of a layout xml file in android

Tags: android, xml

I have a question, I noticed that all my xml files in my android project have the following heading:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

the normal heading of an xml file, I know, but why do all files have it except the layout xml file? Why doesn't eclipse put it during the creation of the project?
Do I need to put this heading or is it option in android project xml file?

Comment: this link will help you
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256048.aspx

Answer (score 1):

An XML declaration is not required in all XML documents; however XHTML document authors are strongly encouraged to use XML declarations in all their documents. Such a declaration is required when the character encoding of the document is other than the default UTF-8 or UTF-16 and no encoding was determined by a higher-level protocol.